# how to retrieve the value from an array - Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am having a table named reports having `(id,form_id,title)`

and another table form`(id,name)`

in my reports.ctp
i am listing all my reports title by fetching it from the table using

```
function reports()
{
    $allreports= $this->Report>find('all',
                                    array('conditions'=>array('Report.user_id'=>$userId),
                                          'group' => array('Report.report_id')));

    foreach($allreports as & $report):
        $report['Report']['formname'] = $this->Form->find('all',
                array(
                    'fields'=>array('Form.name'),
                    'conditions'=>array('Form.id'=>$report['Report']['form_id'])));
    endforeach;

    $this->set('allreports', $allreports);
}
```

i have used foreach to find the corresponding Form name from the Forms table..

in my `reports.ctp`

i want both the reports title and Form name correponding for it one by one like

```
Report1 - Form name - Form1

Report2 - Form name - Form2

Report3 - Form name - Form1
```

i have tried the above using

```
          <div> <a href="#">
                            Reportname:    <?php echo $report['Report']['title'];?>
       </a>
       <a href="#">   Form name <?php echo $report['Report']['formname'];?></a>
         </div>
```

But i am getting as Array for  like

```
Report1 - Form name - Array

Report2 - Form name - Array

Report3 - Form name - Array
```

how to do so?? please suggest me..

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you properly link your models you'll automatically retrieve data for associated models, so your form name would be in `$report['Form']['name']`. There's no need to loop through the retrieved `$reports` and fetch data for them manually, and there's no good reason to require another data format than the one Cake provides you by default.

Comment: You probably want to do what deceze said above.  Use model associations and it will help you retrieve the data you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

`$report['Report']['formname'] = $this->Form->find(...)` 
will return an array. Thats why it says "Array".

If you are going to continue with the logic you are working with... try something more like....

```
foreach($allreports as & $report):
    $temp = $this->Form->read('name',$report['Report']['form_id']);

    $report['Report']['formname']=$temp['Form']['name']
endforeach;
```

But yeah.. you could also go the route of using **CakePHP's** built in relationship features like deceze says. Would be the cleaner way of doing it for sure.